# Format TeXForm at several levels

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, design-patterns

In Mathematica, Format can be used to alter the output formats like TeXForm, OutputForm or TraditionalForm.
This is an example of how one can redefine the TeXForm of a function T.

```
In[1]:= Format[T[a_], TeXForm] := "\[Del]" a
```

The result is

```
In[2]:= TeXForm[T[x]]
Out[1]= x \nabla
```

This is what I expected. Now apply the same format on T[T[x]]

```
In[3]:= TeXForm[T[T[x]]]
Out[2]= \nabla  T(x)
```

However, the output I would like is

```
Out[2]= \nabla \nabla x
```

Why does Mathematica not give this output? And what can I change to get this as output? 
I tried to find more information about formatting in the Mathematica Help and on Stack Overflow, but I could not find many clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to do the formatting manually.

```
myTeX = TeXForm[# /. T -> (Row[{"\[Del]", #}] &)]&;

T[T[a]] //myTeX
```

```
\n abla \n abla a
```

Answer (score 4):

It will work if you don't restrict to TeXForm.

```
In[100] := Format[T[a_]] := \[Del] a

In[101] := TeXForm[T[T[x]]]
Out[101]//TexForm =
           \nabla \nabla x
```

---

Why use `T` when you could use [`Del`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Del.html)?

```
In[7] := Del[a]
Out[7] = ∇a

In[8] := TeXForm[Del[Del[a]]]
Out[8]//TeXForm =
         \nabla \nabla a
```

Comment: In the TeX code I would like to use a different symbol than in the Mathematica output.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this fails is that the `Format[arg, TeXForm]` pattern doesn't recursively distribute `Format` over the arguments.  This isn't unusual.  Consider:

```
Clear[f];
f[T[a_]] := "\[Del]" a;
```

yields `f[T[T[a]]] = "\[Del]" T[a]`, but

```
Clear[f];
f[T[a_]] := "\[Del]" f[a];
```

yields `f[T[T[a]]] = ("\[Del]")^2 f[a]`, which is closer to what you want.

So define

```
Format[T[a_], TeXForm] := f[T[a]]
```

using the second choice of `f[T[a_]]` above, and you'll be off to a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
ESCAPE notation ESCAPE
```

(or choose "Notation" from the palette that opens when you load the package)
In the first placeholder, insert

```
ESCAPE del ESCAPE a_
```

In the second placeholder, enter

```
T[a_]
```

Before the closing bracket of the Notation line, insert the option

```
, WorkingForm -> TraditionalForm
```

Now you can try your example:

```
T[T[a]]//TeXForm
```

and it should give you what you want, except with parentheses (which is advisable in order to maintain your sanity in most cases, anyway):

```
\nabla (\nabla a)
```

You may be able to go further by looking at the Help documents under "Notation/tutorial/OptionsAndAuxiliaryFunctions"

Comment: I'm sure the OP used ESCAPE del ESCAPE in his notebook.  When you cut and paste the result into StackOverflow you get the \Del form.

Comment: ??? I don't think there is any way to get a \Del form... I'm sure you typed ESCAPE del ESCAPE and got \\[Del], exactly as I intended. I'm guessing you're somehow worried that my text can't be cut and pasted. Sorry, but I wanted to be more descriptive for the benefit of readers who may not know the shortcuts.